# DateFormat works with constant string value but not with values from a table

Tags: t-sql, type-conversion

SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

`select CONVERT(DATETIME,'13/2/2022',103).` it returns 2022-02-13 00:00:00.000.

In a table table_3_2_2022_date_string_format, a column holds string date values as below.

1. nonleadingZeroStringDate
   2/3/2022
   23/12/2022
   13/3/2022

   select CONVERT(DATETIME,nonleadingZeroStringDate,103) from table_3_2_2022_date_string_format.

The above script caught an error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

The Microsoft doc says 'The setting of SET DATEFORMAT is set at execute or run time and not at parse time.'. It could explain why it failed?

Answer (score 0):

You're sort of using two different things here. I'm not super familiar with the idiosyncrasies when it comes to dealing with both `DATEFORMAT` and `CONVERT(datetime, [value], ###)` at the same time, but I believe `DATEFORMAT` is really only going to change how date string literals are treated.

By "literals" I mean a date string and you're not giving SQL Server any hints on how to convert it to a date...see below...

```sql
SET DATEFORMAT mdy
SELECT ConversionLiteral = CONVERT(datetime, '2/3/2022')        -- 2022-02-03 00:00:00.000
     , ConversionHint    = CONVERT(datetime, '2/3/2022', 103)   -- 2022-03-02 00:00:00.000

SET DATEFORMAT dmy
SELECT ConversionLiteral = CONVERT(datetime, '2/3/2022')        -- 2022-03-02 00:00:00.000
     , ConversionHint    = CONVERT(datetime, '2/3/2022', 103)   -- 2022-03-02 00:00:00.000
```

When changing the `DATEFORMAT` and using `CONVERT()` without specifying a style, it changes when `DATEFORMAT` changes.

But when you specify a style in the `CONVERT()`, I believe you're telling SQL Server to ignore what `DATEFORMAT` is set to, and instead use style 103, which is `dd/mm/yyyy`.

And this is why no matter what `DATEFORMAT` is set to in the above sample query, the `ConversionHint` value never changes.

---

So, if you are trying to import strings that are all in the format of `dd/mm/yyyy`, then using `CONVERT(datetime, [value], 103)` should work great. But it will throw an error if it tries to convert something like `12/25/2022`.

My suggestion is this...if you are able to use the `TRY_CONVERT()` function. Then run something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime, [value], 103) IS NULL
    AND [value] IS NOT NULL
```

And that will show you which values are failing to convert.

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost every possible way except for adding 0 to make two decimal for day and month. Finally, I had to use the parse() which is not a native SQL function.